# local UUID vs network unique counter id

Tags: mongodb, web-applications, redis, uuid, nosql

Which one will you choose as your surrogate key implementation ?

- Local UUID

  - That is generated locally in the application, no network trip to retrieve it
  - But the length is long, and can affect the size of your storage size usage
  - Lengthy URL with the long UUID
  - The tiniest fear that UUID collision will happen
- Or .. Network-unique-counter id (not sure on what is the proper term for this)

  - I imagine a remote Redis with the atomic INC or Mongo with $inc
  - The cost of network trip
  - Is much shorter, takes up less space and resulting in much shorter URL
  - No fear on collision, even on clustered applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a low concurrency app, you can probably use network counter id.
But except for url, there is no interest for low concurrency (= not a lot of data).

In case of heavy concurrency access, so a lot of data, so a lot of clusters, you redis engine + associated network will be probably to slow for this solution.

In conclusion :
- network counter seems to be sexy but useless, *in my opinion*, with MongoDB.

On MongoDB collision, due to the creation algorithm, the collision is near zero. I explain, a part of the uuid is build with the **machine address**, which should be unique and you can get this address before putting your cluster in production.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MongoDB, you should look into using BSON ObjectIDs:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs

They are created by default as the _id field unless you specify otherwise and create the _id field yourself (which can also be an ObjectID, just created by you).  No fear of collision, and you could get a natively supported ID type in the DB that you can also use in your application.  Seems like a win-win, as long as you use MongoDB of course ;)

Comment: Thanks for insight. Currently i am generating UUID from the app, thinking of taking a little load off mongo.

Comment: If you generate a full UUID similar to mongo's uuid, I strongly recommend to let Mongo generate it for you. So when you will use sharding, Mongo generation will always be faster than yours.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine both approaches. Have a look for twitter's SnowFlake algorithm. The algorithm will produce global unique integers (64bit) but without any coordination, a pure local algortim.